# How to add getlocation in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to add a new `location` field to an existing mongoose schema, I have update the documents in the collection to add the new field `updateMany({}, { $set: { "details.loc": { type: "Point", coordinates: [-0, 0] } } })`
and the field was added...
I also updated the schema to contain

```
...
loc: {
    type: { type: String }
  , coordinates: []
     },
```

with `strict:false` option 
but then when I try to add a new document with location data...it's not reflected

```
db.create( {"details.loc": { type: 'Point', coordinates: [property.lat, property.lang] }});
```

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

As, the reference notation you are using will only work in update document. for create, you'll have to write full object like this

```
db.create( {"details":{"loc": { type: 'Point', coordinates: [property.lat, property.lang] }}});
```